# LINQ is select new necessary for efficiency

Tags: c#, linq

If I am selecting a subset of elements out of a list am I gaining anything by doing a select new to just get only the properties I will be using. Or does the compiler just optimize that out so I can stop encumbering myself with the `select new`, e.g.:

```
var q = from n in TheseGuysHaveABunchOfProperties
        where n.State == "AK" 
        select new { Name = n.Name, Phone = n.Phone };

q.ToList().ForEach(x => Debug.WriteLine(x.Name + x.Phone);
```

vs.

```
var q = from n in TheseGuysHaveABunchOfProperties
        where n.State == "AK" select n;

q.ToList().ForEach(x => Debug.WriteLine(x.Name + x.Phone);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not if you're doing LINQ to Objects. It is more likely to be slower as you copy and allocate more temporary variables. In case of LINQ to SQL, it is the other way around as you reduce the amount of data that is copied from the database.

Edit: This describes the common case. In case of LINQ to Objects, it could be faster copy objects if they are expensive to retrieve, and used more than once in your `select` statement. In case of LINQ to SQL, take case to not select properties you don't actually use.

Comment: OK so for Linq-to-objects method 2 is just as efficient? I wonder if in Linqtosql it optimizes out unused columns so method 2 would be the same.

Comment: If all the properties are lazy-loaded, then ToList() wouldn't mean retrieving all the properties but x.Name and x.Phone would, which is much worse... If the properties are not lazy-loaded, then LINQ2SQL has no way of knowing which properties you will need later on :-)

Comment: @tim: It may not make a big difference but there is additional work involved. An extra object is allocated, and two pointers are copied. Depending on the scenario that could lead to noticable performance differences.

Comment: @Sasha: I dont quite get what point you are making. I will agree that a lot more could be said about the SQL case perhaps, but it is my understanding he is asking about linq to objects.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was answering tim's comment.

Answer (score 2):

First off, @jdv is correct. +1 to him.  I'd like to add that f you are worried about performance, drop the `ToList()`. This is creating a copy of your data just to enumerate over it.  You are now enumerating over it twice.

Instead, use a foreach loop normally:

```
foreach(var x in q)
    Debug.WriteLine(x.Name + x.Phone)
```

If you really like the functional approach of a `ForEach` method, create the extension on `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> set, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(T item in set)
        action(item);
}
```

This will be significantly faster than `ToList().ForEach()`

Answer (score 1):

You generally only use Select New when you want to generate a new type (an anonymous type). It's not really a matter of efficiency but more a matter of what types you need to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

`select new` creates a anonymous type. In case when you don't need it, you probably should not use it.

Rather more efficiency will grant you correct string comparison:

```
where String.Equals(m.State, "AK", StringComparison.Ordinal); // or OrdinalIgnoreCase
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely do want to use `select new`. If `TheseGuysHaveABunchOfProperties` has a lot of properties (and hence data) when you do .ToList() you enumerate the collection completely. So you have a list in memory with every single object with every single property.

By doing `select new` before `ToList`, your objects in the list will only have the two properties you need.

If you can avoid doing `ToList` before `ForEach`, you won't have this problem. Of course the memory use, etc depends on the size of the list and the number of properties in `TheseGuysHaveABunchOfProperties`.